# The problem of shrinking the screen size of the entire program

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-qrcode

I am writing a Flutter project that scans QR codes and I use the qr_code_scanner package
At first, the screen size was good, but now when I run it on my phone, it is smaller from the top and bottom
It is interesting that the program is correct on the smaller phone I had and the emulator, but not on my phone

where is the problem from?

[image]

Comment: Have you fixed height somewhere in your code? Do you use constraintBox?

Comment: Use SafeArea  to resolve this

Comment: and resolve the null issues first  .. check for null ..

Answer (score 0):

If there is SafeArea in your code, you have to remove it, if not, you need to provide, Containter

```
height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

if not, send me your code as a screenshot, let's try another way

Comment: thanks for your answer
I tried the first two ways